# Do html entities in meta tags influence indexing?

Tags: html, seo

I was wondering if using HTML entities in meta tags (like keywords and description) is the best way to go?

Does it influence the indexing from search engines?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd put the meta tags contents without entities as long as my charset allows the chars. I researched a bit and I found this on [Google Webmasters/Site owners help](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=79812) and the example contains **£9.24** not **&pound;9.24** nor **&#163;9.24**

As is true that meta tags aren't a big factor for success, they can be a factor for failure. Indexer robots may detect a try of cheat them by using invalid keywords or description. From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_optimization):

> Early versions of search algorithms
>   relied on webmaster-provided
>   information such as the keyword meta
>   tag, or index files in engines like
>   ALIWEB. Meta tags provide a guide to
>   each page's content. But using meta
>   data to index pages was found to be
>   less than reliable because the
>   webmaster's choice of keywords in the
>   meta tag could potentially be an
>   inaccurate representation of the
>   site's actual content. Inaccurate,
>   incomplete, and inconsistent data in
>   meta tags could and did cause pages to
>   rank for irrelevant searches. Web
>   content providers also manipulated a
>   number of attributes within the HTML
>   source of a page in an attempt to rank
>   well in search engines.

Comment: Duplicating keywords smells of spam. Either use the actual character or use the entity (and if the actual character has special meaning in HTML (like &) then use the entity.

Answer (score 5):

The meta description can be used as the default snippet.

The meta keywords are pretty much completely ignored, but everyone still uses them anyway.

Neither will have much (if any) effect on your ranking, but a good meta description could boost your clickthrough.

Answer (score 3):

Entities make difference only in amateur HTML "parsers" done with regular expressions. They aren't problem for Google.

Answer (score 1):

Meta tags are not ignored. There are still read by Google, so I think, they should be used in the proper way. Google loves pages done in proper way, but remember, that meta tag is one of hundreds things that robots take into consideration.

Comment: so, I understand proper means it has to validate to a xhtml or html spec. in that case, i'll use htmlentities in meta tags, txn

Answer (score 1):

if there are umlaute dont use entities.
i think, google is indexing the word "bremsbeläge" as "bremsbelaege" and "bremsbeläge".

Answer (score 0):

The meta tag "description" does have an effect on the ranking. It is the description that Google gives in the listing, so this is the most important part that influences people to click on your link. When more people click on your link, Google assumes it has more worth for users in the searches and moves you up.