# Razor trying to show text with accents

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, character-encoding

I'm trying to show some text between html tags, I'm using @HTML.Raw method to accomplish this, the code snippet look like this:

```
<!-- SEO -->
<title>@Html.Raw(Model.Title)</title>
<meta name="Description" content="@Html.Raw(Model.Description)">
<meta name="KEYWORDS" content="@Html.Raw(Model.Keywords)">
<!-- END SEO -->

Description: @Html.Raw(Model.Description)
Keywords: @Html.Raw(Model.Keywords)
```

But after the code execute, it show like this:

```
<!-- SEO -->
<title>FÚTBOL - El portal de los hinchas del fútbol</title>
<meta name="Description" content="F&#218;TBOL - El portal de los hinchas del f&#250;tbol">
<meta name="KEYWORDS" content="F&#250;tbol,hinchas">
<!-- END SEO -->
Description: FÚTBOL - El portal de los hinchas del fútbol
Keywords: Fútbol, hinchas
```

Something happend when the escaped string is between the " character.

Does anyone know why is this happening?

**EDIT**

The content of the variables is exactly like this:

```
Title: FÚTBOL - El portal de los hinchas del fútbol
Description: FÚTBOL - El portal de los hinchas del fútbol
Keywords: Fútbol, hinchas
```

The charset and the doctype in my _Layout is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#">
<head>     
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
```

The problem is not the case of the letters its ok that its shows Ú or ú. What i dont unserstand is why its escape the letter in one case and not in the other,

Comment: what's in your `Model.Description` and what `charset` are you using in your `_Layout` view?

Comment: Is `Model.Description` a **user string**, or a sanitized string with known and trusted html in it? (my more immediate concern would be using, or not using. `.Raw` appropriately)

Comment: @MarcGravell Is sanitized, its safe to use the .Raw method.

Comment: @balexandre I update the question to show the info you ask for. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `&x250;` is "ú" and 218 is "Ú" what is the problem? You're just seeing some cases of using an HTML entity and not in other cases.

Providing you're delivering the output with a suitable encoding the end result will be the same – with the entities it'll be the client doing the un-encoding.

Comment: I don't understand your answer: why in one case the @Html.Raw print a `ú` and in another case print a `&x250;`?

Comment: Like you can see its ok that it show the lowercase and the uppercase letter, but what i don't get it is why in one case its show `ú` an in other case its show `&#250;` it most be consistence and show the same characters in both cases.

Comment: @themarcuz: I suspect the difference is attribute vs text nodes being created (rather than in quotes or not). My point: it doesn't matter if the end user on a browser sees the same thing.

Comment: Will a search engine see the same? I'm doing this to create SEO tags.

Comment: @dnlgmzddr I would expect them to be 100% equivalent. But we all know that much software is less functional and more buggy than one might wish. This question might be more helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/q/891977/67392 (albeit most of the answers – including the accepted one – don't answer the question).

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion is use @Html.Raw("your string") whenever you want to force the Raw string.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("Your string with special characters")`

For example:

```cs
Description: @HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Html.Raw(Model.Description))
Keywords: @HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Html.Raw(Model.Keywords))
```

Credits to: [@Hakan Fıstık](https://stackoverflow.com/users/194623/luke-duddridge)

Post: [ASP MVC Razor encode special characters in input placeholder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15246439/asp-mvc-razor-encode-special-characters-in-input-placeholder)