# Html.Raw() and a "TM" character

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm getting xml data which contains some embedded html formatting. I need to display this in an mvc.net razor cshtml page, and I use the Html.Raw() method to do this. However, this same xml data also contains the "TM" characters inline, and for some reason this gets converted into some jumbled text in the html. Not sure what needs to be repaired for this?

Comment: try this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15246439/asp-mvc-razor-encode-special-characters-in-input-placeholder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was actually in retrieving the xml- the webclient was defaulting to a latin charset instead of utf-8, so the tm was being garbled in this step. Forcing it to utf-8 fixed the xml and then the html in the page displayed correctly.