# MVC ListBoxFor missing special char

Tags: c, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an MVC4 app that uses bootstrap
on one view I have

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(x=>x.ids,Model.OPtions,new {@class = "form-control",multiple ="multiple",id ="optionid",data_placeHolder ="Something}
```

`Model.OPtions` have a string value that has special characters in it.
These are being stripped out

It is an `IEmumerable<SelectListItem>`

any ideas?

Comment: What 'special characters'? (and as a side note, add new `{ multiple="multiple" }` is pointless - the `ListBoxFor()` method has already added it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel a fool, it was being created by a an ajax call, someone stuffed a million abstract methods in the javascript file for layoutMaster.js

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use HttpUtility.HtmlEncode as Luke Duddridge pointed out here?
[ASP MVC Razor encode special characters in input placeholder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15246439/asp-mvc-razor-encode-special-characters-in-input-placeholder)