# Store a path with tilde (~) and display it with html.raw in razor

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a razor template index.cshtml and want to store some HTML markup in a variable:

```
@{
    var markup = @"<img src=""~/images/image.png"">";
}
```

Now I want to display it via @Html.Raw() anywhere on the page.

```
<div>    
    @Html.Raw(markup)
</div>
```

The tilde (~) will be shown as expected as a character and not as the root path. So the client will fail to load this wrong image source ~/images/image.png.

Is it possible to get the correct path referenced or converted in the variable like it would be the behavior when the markup was written directly in that view template?

Comment: Did you try putting . or .. or / instead of ~?

Comment: Also, take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/15247805/9233618

Comment: I tried it with and without a leading slash /. Doesn't work and could crash agein later in that project.

Comment: Take a look at the second comment and see if anything there helps.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but my problem is not about encoding/decoding.

Comment: Never, never, never use `@Html.Raw()` in Razor views as it exposes you to cross site scripting vulnerabilities. Use `MvcHtmlString` (.Net 3.5) or `MvcHtmlString` (.Net 4.0) instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [Url.Content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.content?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) method like this:

```
var markup = $@"<img src=""{Url.Content("~/images/image.png")}"">";
```

Or, if you prefer to use `string.Format` instead of `$`:

```
var markup = string.Format(@"<img src=""{0}"">", Url.Content("~/images/image.png"));
```

That will turn "~/images/image.png" into an application absolute path so the actual output will be something like

```
<img src="/images/image.png">
```

Comment: Almost! The double double quotes "" display Url.Content as plain text. But then it should work.

Comment: The `${}` should cause the Url.Content to be executed. It's equivalent to `var markup = string.Format(@"<img src=""{0}"">", Url.Content("~/images/image.png"));`. Did you try it as-is?

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by the modified answer of petelids (Thank you very much)!

```
var rootPath = @Url.Content("~");

var markup = $@"<img src=""{rootPath}/images/image.png"">";
```

For any reason, writing the Url.Content("...") direct into the literal broke the app.

With an extra variable (rootPath) it works.

Comment: Can you paste the code you tried from my answer? I've tested it and it works without issue on my machine.

Comment: I accepted your answer, it's obviously the right syntax. Can't tell you why it broke in my environment.

Comment: Thanks @kmgt, if you ever work it out please feel free to update my answer. I appreciate the accept vote.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
var markup = @"<img src="+Url.Content("~/images/image.png")+">";
```

```
<div>
    @(new HtmlString(markup))
</div>
```