# How to include # symbo in html in ASP.Net MVC view

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to show the 'Account #' on label but code doesn't take it and I get error loading the MVC view.    I changed that # sign to  &num but then it shows as 'Account &num'  What should I do to get 'Account #'

```
 <td class="element-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.AccountNumber, "Account Number") 
 </td>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Do some research. If you get stuck, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [snippet editor](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).

Comment: Please also check [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar question below,
[ASP MVC Razor encode special characters in input placeholder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15246439/asp-mvc-razor-encode-special-characters-in-input-placeholder)

Where if you follow the link @Html.Raw might be the suitable way to get it to render if the encode/etc doesn't work.

Otherwise there are HTML entities that can be used to render what you want, like how it converted it to &num.

https://oinam.github.io/entities/