# are XML entites necessary in attribute values

Tags: html, xhtml

For example is this OK

```
<meta name="description" content="Foo & Bar"/>
```

or should I use this instead:

```
<meta name="description" content="Foo &amp; Bar"/>
```

The doctype of the page in question is HTML5, i.e.

```
<!doctype html>
```

Comment: You mention XML in the title, but HTML and XHTML in the tags. Which is it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/891977/do-html-entities-in-meta-tags-influence-indexing - try googling next time please.

Comment: Entities.... funny word!

Answer (score 2):

In XHTML, which this appears to be about, the first one is not OK, and the second one should be used.

You could quickly check this using the [W3C Markup Validator](http://validator.w3.org/), but the authoritative reference is the XML 1.0 specification, clause 2.4 [Character Data and Markup](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#syntax):

“The ampersand character (&) and the left angle bracket (<) MUST NOT appear in their literal form, except when used as markup delimiters, or within a comment, a processing instruction, or a CDATA section. If they are needed elsewhere, they MUST be escaped using either numeric character references or the strings "`&amp;`" and "`&lt;`" respectively.”